# Can't make it to get javascript to work using webpacker after migrating from the asset pipeline in rails 5.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, webpacker

When attempting to compile I get the following errors for all images:

```
rails assets:precompile
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.symbol' in '/***/app/javascript/packs'




            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /*/app/javascript/core-js/modules/es.symbol.png doesn't exist
            .svg
```

so I get

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Pages#home
```

---

I have installed webpacker by adding in my gemfile

```
gem 'webpacker'
```

and

```
bundle
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
yarn upgrade
yarn install
```

The folder packs in app/javascript was not created, so I created it myself and added my current application.js which was in app/assets to app/javascript/packs/

I added this to the top of the file:

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

And I did replace all tags with

```
javascript_pack_tag
```

or

```
asset_pack_path
```

but my manifest file looks anyways like:

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-e4e1539847422.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-e4e15391747422.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-e4e15391a97422.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-e4391598747422.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Without changing anything apparently the images get compiled correctly and **when I Have access to my app the javascript does not work.**

Comment: What files do you have in `app/config/webpack`? Also try rake assets:clobber then try compiling again. Try removing the `imports` from your packs and see if it compiles then. I have a feeling your `config/webpack/environment.js` file is the issue. You may want to look into adding `core-js` to the environment. Look at how this tutorial added jQuery to webpacker https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/rails-6-jquery-upgrade-with-webpacker. I think you will need something similar.

Comment: in `app/config/webpack`I have development.js, production.js, test.js , environment.js...

Comment: trying `rakke assets:clobber` did not work either (same results).

Comment: Thanks the article helped although not all the javascript is loaded yet, and bootstrap related elements like dropdowns are not working.

Answer (score 3):

Delete this files and folders:

```sh
/node_modules
/tmp/cache
yarn.lock
Gemfile.lock
```

and then run:

```sh
bundle install
rails webpacker:install
rails assets:precompile
rails webpacker:compile
```

Comment: I followed those steps and When doing `rails assets:precompile`  the opration gets halted due to: `ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.symbol.description'`

Comment: @Gotey try to remove `webpacker` gem and add it with: `yarn add @rails/webpacker` and then restart the process